# Data not showing until I start to filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I am trying to use the data binding feature of AngularJS to show a list of data I send an Ajax request for. I am new to AngularJS so I know I'm missing something here. The data is being populated but it only shows if I include a text box with the `ng-model` directive and begin typing in it.

I know my code isn't exactly best practice but I'm trying to do this in SharePoint and I'm having trouble using Modules and Factories so I'm trying to get a simple demo setup first. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Code**

```html
<!-- The data will not show until I start typing in this text box
Other than that I do not need it. -->
<input ng-model="foo" />

<ul ng-controller="SimpleController">
     <li ng-repeat="item in discussions">
         {{item.Title}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

```js
function SimpleController($scope) {                        
  $.ajax({
     url: requestUri,
     type: "GET",
     headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
     },
     success: function (data) {
        $scope.discussions = data.d.results;      
        console.log("SimpleController success callback");
     },
     error: function (err) {
        alert(err);
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle which reproduces the problem?

Comment: Working on reproducing it outside of SharePoint... I can't really replicate the exact environment I'm working in.

Comment: Try `$scope.$apply()` after setting `$scope.discussions = data.d.results;` and see if it works this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what's happening is Angular does not know when the `$.ajax` call is complete, so you could technically use `if ( $scope.$$phase ) $scope.$apply()`, but I'd recommend rebuilding `$.ajax` "The Angular Way":

```
function SimpleController($scope, $http) {
  $http.get( requestUri )
  .then(function( json ) {
    console.log( json );
    $scope.discussions = json.data;
  });
}
```

More reading:

- [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http): manually tell Angular to recalculate scope upon changing data outside of Angular data, e.g. jQuery.
- [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http): Angular version of `$.ajax` and automatically handles `$scope.$apply` (recommended)